# Хранение пользователей в Базе Данных

Tags: база-данных, facebook-api, instagram-api

Как организовать структуру таблицы для хранения пользователей, которые как зарегистрировались на сайте, так и авторизовались на сайте через FB или instagram. Пока что есть идея сделать стандартные поля и поле password для пользователей, которые использовали сервисы, оставить пустым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все достаточно просто. Главное соблюдать нормализацию БД.

1 - Если вы уверены, что больше соц-сетей не добавится, то можно добавить в основную таблицу 2 поля (FB и Instagram) и задать им bool значения.

2 - Если вы планируете еще соц сети и увелечение Бд, то лучше создать отдельную таблицу, где будите хранить данные о авторизованности юзеров.